# compile Library from shell script

Tags: iphone

I want to integrate OCR in my iphone application. For that I found a library and sample example [PocketOCR](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR). When I download this example it gives me compile time errors that few frameworks are missing. After googling I found that I need to compile library. I don't know how to do this. [Here](http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/07/15/cross-compiling-for-iphone-dev-884) I got shell script but what exactly to do with this script?

Please help me to know that what to do with this shell script and how?
Is there any tutorial to know this.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this script at the top of ur library source. Also check whether u have set the correct SDKROOT & DEVROOT.

Edit: I guess u r not having correct source code. Try again with new downloaded source code, which will have makefile. I just checked about that. There I found the makefiles in the source.

Comment: Right now I have ios version 4.3 installed. I want to compile this library to support on 3.0. Do i need to install ios version 3.0?

Comment: My SDKROOT is referencing to `iPhoneOS3.0.sdk` I dont have this folder do i need to change it with my availability

Comment: Yes, u should compile the library with the available version. U need not to install iOS3.0 SDK. Instead change the path in the script to point to iOS4.3.

Comment: So in case this will work with a application having iOS 3.0 right?
Second thing after putting all library files and script in the same folder what to do..? Should I have to use `sudo ./build_fat.sh`

Comment: I tried this too.. If you look at the github source code there are two folder tessdata and tessdata-svn. I tried three combination.. 1)my .sh file + tessdata + tessdata-svn in a folder
2)my .sh file in tessdata
3)my .sh file in tessdata-svn 
then open terminal and go to the folder execute the `sudo ./build_fat.sh` asking for password but the result is `sudo: ./build_fat.sh: command not found`

Comment: Thats colons should not come after sudo. 1)my .sh file +.... That is correct. Change to the directory in the terminal. Make the script executable by `chmod +x build_fat.sh`. Then give `sudo ./build_fat.sh`

Comment: I got following response `./build_fat.sh: line 1: ld_fat.sh: command not found
./build_fat.sh: line 35: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: ccmain/libtesseract_full.a: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target \`distclean'.  Stop.
./build_fat.sh: line 61: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: ccmain/libtesseract_full.a: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: lnsout/libtesseract_full.a.arm (No such file or directory)`

Comment: I guess u have not deleted any file , mainly make files. Just before giving ./build_.., give `ls -a`  . Check whether it lists makefile.

Comment: @Gomathi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1502/discussion-between-kapil-choubisa-and-gomath)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you are using Mac. Open Terminal, navigate to the directory where you put the script. Assume you name the script as suggested : build_fat.sh , run the command below:

```
sudo ./build_fat.sh
```

Type in your password and let it run.

Comment: How to put this script on any path..? Just by copy paste or any other way to put the script..

Comment: I tried but its giving error `sudo: ./build_fat.sh: command not found`

Comment: you have to create the script file first. paste the code to a new file using vi or vim .